# Why does opening a CSV force Excel to recalculate all workbooks?

Tags: excel, csv, vba

Why does Excel calculate **all** open workbooks when I run this example VBA code?  Is there any way to stop it?

```
Public Sub Test()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Test.csv"
End Sub
```

It seems only to happen with CSV file-types.

I also get the same behaviour when updating PivotTables programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first do EnableCalculation = False in all the worksheets that have calculation. After that open csv file.

Hopefully something like this will work:

```
 Public Sub Test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
       ws.EnableCalculation = Flase
    Next ws

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Test.csv"
End Sub
```

You may need to do EnableCalculations = True after you successfully import the Test.csv file.

If you could upload the excel file where I can download, I will try to help you with this.